# Can a key be changed for said stored encryption with PHPs LibSodium?

Tags: php, encryption, libsodium

As the title suggests, can an encrypted data's key be changed once it's been set without resetting the original data with the LibSodium PHP library?

I've searched high and low but I can't seem to find anything!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Short answer: no. You have to decrypt the data with the old key and re-encrypt with the new key.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Fehr's comment on the original post is correct:

> Short answer: no. You have to decrypt the data with the old key and re-encrypt with the new key.